# Arduino Uno + USB Host Shield + Motor Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

We have an obstacle avoiding robot, and we decided to upgrade it by controlling it with a PS3 controller, so I am asking if above the Arduino UNO we can attach the USB host and above the Host attach the motor shield where the motors are connected to?

Comment: Read the documentation for both shields and see which (if any) pins they share, then decided if these pins can be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the I/O used by each shield to make sure there is no conflicts.